# Populating a table dynamically with the java web-service returns

Tags: java, jquery, web-services, datatable

I'm trying to implement a basic web application from the values that we are getting from web-service, it will include two datatables, each of them need to be populated in server-side.

For example, web-service have a structure like this ( Let's say these are books)

Firstly i am getting the string GUID value for the objects that i want to get an information, after that i am sending a request with the parameter of this GUIDs to service to get information XML for these book objects that includes name, page and author of them.

But as an important information, my servlet needs to get these values dynamically as soon as the page of datatable is changed, if this datatable will include 30 book ( i will get the 30 guid firstly so i can clarify that ) after that, send one request for 10 of them to show them on first page of datatable, if user clicked on page two, server behind needs to send request for the other group of ten and returns me result to show on the table.

I tried to implement the structure below :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/359750/jQuery-DataTables-in-Java-Web-Applications#ServerSideProcessing

but it populates a table with the DataRepository ones with all of them, so with this point of view i can't use it dynamically as i totally requested.

The main need for this, XML return for many objects needs so long time.

So do you know any example link or tutorial such a need for this ?

Thank you for informations in advance!

Answer (score 0):

@Hayra, thanks for providing the Code Project link to the JQuery-DataTable example, it is very helpful.  This is something that I might implement soon.

What I understood from the example, the JQuery-DataTable keeps track for you specific parameters that will allow you to return the exact number of records.  The specific parameters that you need are "iDisplayStart" and the iDisplayLength".  The "iDisplayLength" is set when the user specifies 10 records per page and the iDisplayStart, will is set when the page number changes.

So look at the code in the Code Project example doGet Method, this section of the code returns only the subset of records back to your table.

```
JQueryDataTableParamModel param = DataTablesParamUtility.getParam(request);
        if(companies.size()< param.iDisplayStart + param.iDisplayLength) {
            companies = companies.subList(param.iDisplayStart, companies.size());
        } else {
            companies = companies.subList(param.iDisplayStart, param.iDisplayStart + param.iDisplayLength);
        }

        try {
            JsonObject jsonResponse = new JsonObject();         
            jsonResponse.addProperty("sEcho", sEcho);
            jsonResponse.addProperty("iTotalRecords", iTotalRecords);
            jsonResponse.addProperty("iTotalDisplayRecords", iTotalDisplayRecords);

            for(Company c : companies){
                JsonArray row = new JsonArray();
                row.add(new JsonPrimitive(c.getName()));
                row.add(new JsonPrimitive(c.getAddress()));
                row.add(new JsonPrimitive(c.getTown()));
                data.add(row);
            }
            jsonResponse.add("aaData", data);

            response.setContentType("application/Json");
            response.getWriter().print(jsonResponse.toString());

        } catch (JsonIOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            response.getWriter().print(e.getMessage());
        }
```

I hope this help

Comment: @Hayra, I just implemented the jQuery.datatable plugin and it seems you do not need to go through the trouble of implementing the doGet method if you have a small amount of records to show in the table (30 to 100).  It is recommended for high number of records.  All I did is download the jquery.datatables.min.js and jquery.datatables.css and added just the following,

Comment: sorry, I hit return.   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />   <script type="text/javascript">               

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
   $(document).ready(function () {      $('#t01').DataTable();
    });
where the #t01 is my table id.  It worked just fine and it only displayed 10 records for each page

Comment: Firstly  thanks for your answers, but i  actually got how it works, even that in the example, it shows it 10 by 10 but, it populates the table ones a time, it gets all the results firstly, then show it on the table. It works a kind of statically... My point is that get the results 10 by 10 on the server and give the json according to these files. Table knows that it will have 30 entries, and create 3 pages. But every page will be populated dynamically. It will process web-service client request too while doing processing...